# Node JS Net.Connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js

I created a very simple Node.JS script which is suppose to connect to a server on port 3200.  The code works great on Windows 8.1 x64, but when I moved it to a Ubuntu Server machine I am getting a ECONNREFUSED.

I tried to connect via IP Address and the Domain Name, but neither work.  It always gives me ECONNREFUSED.

When I SSH into the Ubuntu Server I can do a telnet to the server/port and it works fine. Also pinging the server works.  Just Node.JS doesnt connect.

Server:
Ubuntu Server 12.04.3 LTS (precise)

Here is the code:

```
var net = require('net');

var socket = net.connect({port: 3200, host: '172.19.16.203'},  function() { 

    // Connection Successful
    console.log('Socket connected...');

    // Data Received from Server
    socket.on('data', function(d) {
        console.log('data');         
    });

    socket.on('end', function() {            
    });

    socket.on('error', function(e) {             
    });
});
```

Comment: did you check the file permissions?

Comment: I am running the program with sudo

Comment: did you tried to run on `127.0.0.1` and on a different port, say `9999`?

Comment: Well I am not running the server on the same machine.  The host is on another server.  But from the terminal I can telnet into the IP/Port and it works fine.  I upgraded to the latest node.js but still nothing.

Comment: I just created another NodeJS script which listens on port 58292.  It'll accept a connection and send a message then disconnect.

I changed my script from above to connect to this local port but I still get the same error.

Comment: looks like

var socket = net.createConnection(port,ip); works... just not net.connect()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.  I was running my script by the following command:

node test.js

I guess the node is an old version.  I upgraded the OS to the latest version and then did:

apt-get install nodejs

I run the script like following:

nodejs test.js

And it works!